# Log payment transactions from multiple sources

Tags: apache-kafka, event-log

in our current setup we have two different platforms where users can buy (through different flows) the same thing. Each platform is logging the payment flow (= checkout, order status, payment status etc) in its own database with different properties, different statuses, different steps, but it is time to unify this operation.

My first thought was to have both systems produce the same logs as events to a kafka, process them to transform into a new, common record and them sink them to a db. Eventually, a react app can present these logs per need.

I am wondering whether this is the right approach and if someone has any feedback or ideas about it.

Comment: React doesn't have a Kafka library (Kafka clients are only for NodeJS backend, not JS frontend), but sure, the rest sounds fine. What issues are you running into when making a POC?

Comment: Thanks for correction, i meant since data are in a database, then they are usable and exposable to the user.
I got disheartened by AWS not allowing public MSK for security reasons during creation. Thought at first place that it would be bad practice

Comment: Not sure what you mean [MSK allows public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/public-access.html)

Comment: MSK also disables enabling public access *during creation*, i was thinking it could be considered anti-pattern to enabled.

Comment: Regardless, Kafka is a backend technology. Your React app needs to send API calls to some _other_ public API endpoint backend server (Nodejs, or other) that can then send requests to Kafka. Therefore, Kafka wouldn't be public anyway. The database is also not public.